# Blur/Focus event getting triggered multiple times

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use a combination of Visibility API and blur/focus which I got from :
https://stereologics.wordpress.com/2015/04/02/about-page-visibility-api-hidden-visibilitychange-visibilitystate/
to cover all cases ( tab change, minimize, ALT+TAB, META+L etc ) since visibility API only works when the document is hidden but it doesnt work with ALT+TAB, META+L etc. The problem is that the blur/Focus event is getting triggered multiple times as follows:

1. In chrome while minimizing/maximizing window blur/focus fires 3 times  but only single time in all the other cases.
2. In firefox while switching application using ALT+TAB and then returning back blur/focus is fired 3 times but only single time in all the other cases.

here is the sample code :

**welcome.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="./src.js"></script
    <meta content="">
    <style></style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

**src.js**

```
var browserPrefixes = ['moz', 'ms', 'o', 'webkit'],
    isVisible = true; // internal flag, defaults to true

// get the correct attribute name
function getHiddenPropertyName(prefix) {
  return (prefix ? prefix + 'Hidden' : 'hidden');
}

// get the correct event name
function getVisibilityEvent(prefix) {
  return (prefix ? prefix : '') + 'visibilitychange';
}

// get current browser vendor prefix
function getBrowserPrefix() {
  for (var i = 0; i < browserPrefixes.length; i++) {
    if(getHiddenPropertyName(browserPrefixes[i]) in document) {
      // return vendor prefix
      return browserPrefixes[i];
    }
  }

  // no vendor prefix needed
  return null;
}

// bind and handle events
var browserPrefix = getBrowserPrefix(),
    hiddenPropertyName = getHiddenPropertyName(browserPrefix),
    visibilityEventName = getVisibilityEvent(browserPrefix);

function onVisible() {
  // prevent double execution
  if(isVisible) {
    return;
  }
 
  // change flag value
  isVisible = true;
  console.log('visible'); //gets printed 3 times in both of the above mentioned cases
}

function onHidden() {
  // prevent double execution
  if(!isVisible) {
    return;
  }

  // change flag value
  isVisible = false;
  console.log('hidden'); //gets printed 3 times in both of the above mentioned cases
}

function handleVisibilityChange(forcedFlag) {
  // forcedFlag is a boolean when this event handler is triggered by a
  // focus or blur eventotherwise it's an Event object
  if(typeof forcedFlag === "boolean") {
    if(forcedFlag) {
      return onVisible();
    }

    return onHidden();
  }

  if(document[hiddenPropertyName]) {
    return onHidden();
  }

  return onVisible();
}

document.addEventListener(visibilityEventName, handleVisibilityChange, false);

// extra event listeners for better behaviour
document.addEventListener('focus', function() {
  handleVisibilityChange(true);
}, false);

document.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  handleVisibilityChange(false);
}, false);

window.addEventListener('focus', function() {
    handleVisibilityChange(true);
}, false);

window.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  handleVisibilityChange(false);
}, false);
```

you can also find the code at this link I mentioned above: https://stereologics.wordpress.com/2015/04/02/about-page-visibility-api-hidden-visibilitychange-visibilitystate/

I need the events fired only once for each possible scenario of page hidden/inactive because I have to throw a Modal and right now the modal is getting fired multiple times in the above two mentioned cases. Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you adding the event listeners to both `document` and `window`? That will make it run twice.

Comment: Even after removing listeners from document it still shows the same behaviour.